# UsernameView unexpectedly flashes briefly after force closing and reopening app

Tags: swiftui

I'm facing an odd behaviour in my SwiftUI application where the UsernameView briefly appears and then disappears just a few seconds after the user force closes and reopens the app, even though they have completed the onboarding process and have a username stored.

```swift
@MainActor
final class RootViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var userUsername: [UserUsername] = []
    
    @Published var hasUsername: Bool = false
    
    func getUsername() async throws {
        let authDataresult = try AuthenticationManager.shared.getAuthenticatedUser()

        self.userUsername =  try await UserManager.shared.getUsername(userId: authDataresult.uid)

        hasUsername = self.userUsername.count >= 1
    }
}

struct RootView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = RootViewModel()
    
    @State private var showSignInView: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if showSignInView {
                NavigationStack {
                    AuthenticationView(showSignInView: $showSignInView)
                }
            } else if !viewModel.hasUsername {
                UsernameView(hasUsername: $viewModel.hasUsername)
                
            } else {
                TabbarView(showSignInView: $showSignInView)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            
            let authUser = try? AuthenticationManager.shared.getAuthenticatedUser()
            self.showSignInView = authUser == nil ? true : false
            
            Task {
                // Check for authUser before calling getUsername
                if let authenticatedUser = authUser {
                    // Handle authenticated user scenario:
                    print("User signed in with uid: \(authenticatedUser.uid)")
                    try? await viewModel.getUsername() // Pass uid to getUsername
                    print(viewModel.userUsername.count)
                } else {
                    print("No user signed in!")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if the view is being shown when `showSignInView` is true only, there must be someplace where this is set to true, like in the **onAppear**. Without more info I can't say for sure, but definitely there some part of your code that is setting it to true when it shouldn't. It could be that the call to `AuthenticationManager.shared.getAuthenticatedUser()` returns nil so `showSignInView` is set to true there.

Answer (score -1):

You have a few mistakes. In SwiftUI you shouldn't have view models since that is the job of the `View` data struct. To use async/await it is `.task` not `Task`. Should should not use `DispatchQueue.main.async` because `View` structs are value types they have no lifetime. Try breaking the problem up into multiple `View` structs. Use `.task(id: user.id)` to fetch the username. `overlay` is a good way to show the sign in screen because then you can avoid the `if` in the main body.